# Sum rows in SAP Webi 4.1 report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a report in Webi which is similar to below example (Upper table).

[image]

What I want to build is the lower table, i.e. to sum up the values of "A" and "B" and show it in one row.

How to achieve this in BO Webi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on BI4, then this is actually pretty easily done.  First, Control-click on the A and B cells to select both:

[image]

Right-click on one of the selected cells, then hit Group -> Group:

[image]

Give the group a meaningful name (taking the name "A+B" from your example):

[image]

This will create a new Group and replace the original variable in the report block:
[image]

You'll see the new variable under "Variables" in the Available Objects panel, and can modify it from there if necessary.

If you are not on BI4, or if you just prefer to enter a variable manually, you can do that too.  Replace the Forecast column with:

```
=If [Forecast] InList ("A";"B") Then "A+B" Else [Forecast]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see "Group" option, when I right click after selecting both A and B. All other things I see, like "Filter", "Start Drill", "Edit Formula", etc. I tried many times, no success. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You may be in the HTML panel; try the Java panel instead.

Comment: No, I tried it in Java many times. However, I also tried it in HTML, but there I see very few things after right click. WHat is actually BI4? I just learned that we have BO4 Version, and not 4.1.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  The group functionality was introduced in 4,1.  You will need to use the second method I described above.

Comment: I tried your second solutioin, and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.